# Python datetime.strptime issue

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to parse a date time string to datetime type, here is my code:

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2002 00:00:00', "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")
```

However, I've got an error:

> ValueError: time data '01/01/2002 00:00:00' does not match format
>   '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'

May I know how to fix this?

Many thanks.

Comment: As others have pointed out, capitalisation is important for the datetime format, there's actually a ton of parameters. You can see all of them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: You might want to consider using the [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/)  library. It makes live with date/time in python much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Your year format is incorrect. It should be a capital `Y`:

```
>>> print datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2002 00:00:00', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
2002-01-01 00:00:00
```

I'm sure you've seen it, but the documentation for the possible values is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: You posted seconds before me, so I admit defeat ;) Just want to point out that in your answer the `%d` and `%m` have switched positions. The OP has them the other way around. It's hard to say which is correct because of the date used in the example. [ISO8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/)!

Comment: Are you sure? Either I'm missing it or the OP edited, but my code matches what is posted. Your [PSA](https://xkcd.com/1179/) is spot on though

Comment: You are right. That's funny, I copied from the question, but now I can't see any edits. Never mind! Maybe they changed something in the Matrix. **Edit** or it's the confusing "grace period".

Answer (score 1):

You should change `%y` to `%Y`, for year with full century.

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('01/01/2002 00:00:00', "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Please see the [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) section of the datetime docs.